# Can not call a method from inside another method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods, prototype

Check my code below, I am just lost here why am I getting this error. Any suggestion please. 
Here I have made a class test and added two methods check and nextfn. I am calling check from nextfn.

```
var test=function(){}

test.prototype.check=function()
{
  console.log("hello from checking");
}

test.prototype.nextFn=function(){

  check();

  console.log("Hello from nextfn");
}
```

Next

```
var t=new test();
t.nextfn();
```

The error is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined(…)
```

Now consider another scenario;

```
test.prototype.anotherFn=function()
{
    var p=new Promise(function(){
         this.check();
    })
}
```

Now also getting same error;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined(…)
```

When calling

```
var t=new test();
t.anotherFn();
```

Comment: `this.check();`

Comment: Also, `new test()` instead of `new text()`

Comment: to expand on @Igor comment, the `check` method was put on the prototype of test. `nextFn` is part of the same prototype, `this` is a keyword referring to the parent/prototype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `check` function is on the [prototype](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) of the `test` object.

When you invoke `nextFn` like this:

```
t.nextfn();
```

The ensuing scope will be bound to the `t` instance of "type" `test`. Access within `nextfn` to `test`'s prototype will be available via `this`.

So access `check` using `this`:

```
this.check();
```

This stuff can get surprisingly confusing. A good reference is [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures).

====

For your second scenerio, the problem is that you are trying to invoke `this` from within a function that has it's own scope.

Scope in JavaScript is generally not block scoped, but rather *function scoped*. There is a lot more to it, and I would recommend reading a tutorial on closures to get a more rounded description, but for now, try this instead:

```
test.prototype.anotherFn=function()
{
    var self = this; // save reference to current scope
    var p=new Promise(function(){
         self.check(); // use self rather than this
    })
}
```

Comment: Worked well, now added another scenario in my question; can you please clarify this one also please. I understand that it is now going to the scope of p. But how to call the function check then?

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL I updated my answer for the second part of the question